# What if two people balefire each other at the same time?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, magical-theory

It is a dark and stormy night.  A howling wind stirs up, gathering dust.  Two channelers stand, seperated by ten yards of dust, and each one shoots balefire at the other one.  The balefires hit the other person at the same time and have the same strength.  What happens?  Do they both die, or do their balefires both cancel out the other person's balefire? Or does this create an infinite paradox that ends the world?

Comment: Erm, they both die?

Comment: Simultaneous events are impossible, according to Einstein...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suicide by balefire](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95573/suicide-by-balefire)

Comment: It's not suicide, they each balefire the other person.

Comment: @Mithrandir I feel like simultaneity varies depending on the observer, but there is an observer who will see both events as simultaneous. Besides, unless we're talking about picoseconds here, the two events will be simultaneous to everybody on the planet.

Comment: Like, do they both die or both survive?

Comment: I think they both survive. Mostly due to the fact that they are cancelling out their use of Balefire on each other.

Comment: Don't cross the streams! :)

Comment: I think they would both survive initially then crumble to dust or fall into unending cracks in the earth due to the damage that the balefire did to the fabric of time being multiplied by balefire undoing what had just been done physically by a separate balefire.